# convert sqlalchemy query result to a list of dicts

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to have the result of my query converted to a list of dicts like this :

```
result_dict = [{'category': 'failure', 'week': '1209', 'stat': 'tdc_ok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}, {'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}]
```

But instead I get it as a dict, thus with repeated keys:

```
result_dict = {'category': 'failure', 'week': '1209', 'stat': 'tdc_ok', 'severityDue': '2_critic', 'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}
```

I get this result by doing this :

```
for u in my_query.all():
     result_dict = u.__dict__
```

How can I convert sqlAlchemy query result to a list of dicts (each row would be a dict) ?

Help please

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try

```
result_dict = [u.__dict__ for u in my_query.all()]
```

Besides what is the type of *your* `result_dict` before the `for` loop? Its behavior is rather strange.

Answer (score 9):

This works now

```
result_dict = [u._asdict() for u in my_query.all()]
```

The reason is that u is not actually a tuple but a KeyedTuple.

The correct answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624530/return-sqlalchemy-results-as-dicts-instead-of-lists) also would be helpful

Comment: [row.__dict__ for row in User.query.all()]

Answer (score 3):

There's no [.all()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy)

You can try:

```
result_dict = [u.__dict__ for u in my_query.fetchall()]
```

Comment: it depends on if you are using the ORM or not (the OP did not specify). `.all()` is a `fetchall()` proxy for ORM queries.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is because a few years have passed since the original post, but the following works for me (the others did not)...

```
result_dict = [dict(u) for u in my_query.fetchall()]
```

I am working in core, not ORM.