# Return SQLAlchemy results as dicts instead of lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I examine the results of a query, it looks like a list of lists.  I want to return a list of dicts mapping column names to result values.  How can I convert the result rows to dicts?

```
results = db.session.query(
    PendingPost.campaign_id.label('campaign_id'),
    Campaign.title.label('title'),
    sqlalchemy.func.count(PendingPost.status).label('status_count'),
).join(
    Campaign, Campaign.id == PendingPost.campaign_id,
).join(
    Areas, Areas.id == PendingPost.area_id
).filter(
    sqlalchemy.func.month(PendingPost.creation_date) == datetime.datetime.utcnow().month
).group_by(
    PendingPost.status,
    PendingPost.campaign_id,
).all()

print(results)
[(3, 'campaign title', 1),
 (4, 'campaign title', 1)]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The results *look* like tuples/lists, but they are actually a special [`Row`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) object ([`KeyedTuple`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) for SQLAlchemy < 1.4).  Use the `_asdict()` method to convert each row to a dict.

```
return [r._asdict() for r in results]
[{'campaign_id': 3, 'title': 'campaign title', 'status_count': 1},
 {'campaign_id': 4, 'title': 'campaign title', 'status_count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 11):

in Python 3.7 / SQLAlchemy 1.3.18 this works for me:

```
return [dict(r) for r in results]
```

Answer (score 3):

As of SQLAlchemy 1.4 and above, the “KeyedTuple” object returned by Query is replaced by Row.  [See here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_14.html#the-keyedtuple-object-returned-by-query-is-replaced-by-row).

This means that this will no longer work:

```
[dict(r) for r in row_list]
```

I was able to get it working in SQLAlchemy 2.0 with this subtle change:

```
[dict(r._mapping) for r in row_list]
```