# Retrieve query results as dict in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask SQLAlchemy and I have the following code to get users from database with raw SQL query from a MySQL database:

```py
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from User where id=0")
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

`results` variable is a tuple and I want it to be of type dict(). Is there a way to achieve this?

when I was using pymysql to build the db connection I was able to do

```py
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Is there something similar in SQLAlchemy?

Note: The reason I want to do this change is to get rid of using pymysql in my code, and only use SQLAlcehmy features, i.e. I do not want to have ´´´import pymysql´´´ in my code anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return SQLAlchemy results as dicts instead of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624530/return-sqlalchemy-results-as-dicts-instead-of-lists)

Comment: No I have tried to apply this solution it does not work as I mentioned in my question I am using engine.raw_connection which returns tuples not named tuples same applies to your comment IIja
I got this error message
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_asdict'

Comment: I think the old title of my question was better describing my need

Comment: @malsioufi Right, entirely missed the fact that you're using raw connections, which invalidates my previous comment. I also agree that the old title was more fitting. But a good question then is: why are you using raw connections?

Comment: What I am doing is updating my application from using pymysql to use SQLAlchemy. In many places in the code 

```cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) cursor.execute(some_statment) ```

is used so I think if there is a way to keep this behavior as it is for now and just update the connection object (conn) from being a pymysql object to SQLAlchemy one.  
In other words, I want to keep this part
 ```python 
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from User where id=0")
results = cursor.fetchall()```

Comment: out of curiosity - any share-worthy reason you prefer not to use pymysql?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> results is a tuple and I want it to be of type dict()

*Updated answer for SQLAlchemy 1.4:*

Version 1.4 has deprecated the old `engine.execute()` pattern and changed the way `.execute()` operates internally. `.execute()` now returns a [CursorResult](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult) object with a [.mappings()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.mappings) method:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

with engine.begin() as conn:
    qry = sa.text("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM clients WHERE ID < 3")
    resultset = conn.execute(qry)
    results_as_dict = resultset.mappings().all()
    pprint(results_as_dict)
    """
    [{'FirstName': 'Gord', 'LastName': 'Thompson'}, 
     {'FirstName': 'Bob', 'LastName': 'Loblaw'}]
    """
```

---

*(Previous answer for SQLAlchemy 1.3)*

SQLAlchemy already does this for you if you use `engine.execute` instead of `raw_connection()`. With `engine.execute`, `fetchone` will return a SQLAlchemy `Row` object  and `fetchall` will return a `list` of `Row` objects. `Row` objects can be accessed by key, just like a `dict`:

```python
sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM clients WHERE ID = 1"
result = engine.execute(sql).fetchone()
print(type(result))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.Row'>
print(result['FirstName'])  # Gord
```

If you need a true `dict` object then you can just convert it:

```python
my_dict = dict(result)
print(my_dict)  # {'FirstName': 'Gord', 'LastName': 'Thompson'}
```

Comment: What I am actually doing is updating my application from using pymysql to use SQLAlchemy. and in many places in the code


```python
 cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute(some_statment)
```

is used so I thought if there is a way to keep this behavior as it is for now and just update the connection object (conn) from being a pymysql object to SQLAlchemy one. That's why I did not want to solve the issue with engine.execute(), because this requires me to do a lot of changes in my code which I do not want to do right now

Comment: This works just for the top-level select fields, but not for aggregators, e.g. `func.array_agg` - how can you make it work for those too?

Answer (score 3):

you can use sqlalchemy cursor and cursor's description.

```html
def rows_as_dicts(cursor):
    """convert tuple result to dict with cursor"""
    col_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    return [dict(zip(col_names, row)) for row in cursor]


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# get cursor
cursor = db.session.execute(sql).cursor
# tuple result to dict
result = rows_as_dicts(cursor)
```

Comment: Works great for 2.0.x as well

Answer (score 1):

If `raw_connection()` is returning a PyMySQL `Connection` object then you can continue to use `DictCursor` like so:

```python
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:whatever@localhost:3307/mydb")
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo, 'two' AS bar")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)  # [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 'two'}]
```

Comment: I think there is something missing in my question( I will add it now) that I want to get rid of using pymysql anywhere in the code since SQLAlchemy is using it under the hood. But it seems to be impossible to do so right now.

Answer (score -2):

I would personally use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
connection = engine.raw_connection()
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * from User where id=0' , connection)
mydict = df.to_dict()
```

Comment: What I am actually doing is updating my application from using pymysql to use SQLAlchemy. and in many places in the code
```python
 cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute(some_statment)
```
is used so I thought if there is a way to keep this behavior as it is for now and just update the connection object (conn) from being a pymysql object to SQLAlchemy one. That's why I did not want to solve the issue with engine.execute(), because this requires me to do a lot of changes in my code which I do not want to do right now